# How to save the result of feature selection in Weka?

Tags: weka, feature-selection, rweka, information-gain

I’m trying to use InfoGainAttributeEval in Weka for feature selection, how to save the result? I try to save it but seems like my weka just save my input data, not the result of feature selection.

Comment: Hi there, what actions are you taking to try to save the result?

Comment: In the result view, I'm using "save reduced data" but when I check the result my weka just saves the input data that I use. Is there any other way to save the result?

Comment: I'm not a Weka user, but hopefully that extra information can bring in some answers.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. As far as I understand you want to get the ranked values of the attributes. To do this, right click on the "Ranker + InfoGainAttributeEval" statement in the "Result List" section. Select "Save result buffer". You can see the results in programs such as notepad. You can also import it into "Excel" and create it in the chart. I think you selected "Ranker" in the Search Method section. I think it is an image as seen in the figure below.

[image: weka_result_buffer_screen]

After selecting and running "InfoGainAttributeEval" and "Ranker" it will give you a "ranked" list (Use full training set). Right click and select "Save Reduced Data" then save. Open the file in notepad as well. Open in Weka too. Select the ones whose Rank value is 0 in Weka and delete them with "Remove". Let those with rank value be left. Now you can get the same result reduced with these features. Save in .arff format. Now you have acquired Reduced data.

Answer (score 0):

If "Save Reduced Data" is not working for you,  here is another approach.

Attribute selection can be accomplished in the `Preprocess` tab.
There is a bar near the top for Filtering the data. Click the
"Choose" button. Under `Filters->Supervised->Attribute` you will
find `AttributeSelection`.  Select that.

[image: Selection of AttributeSelection filter]

Once it says "AttributeSelection" in the Filter bar, you can click
on the bar to pick a selection method and a search method as well as
set the parameters for those choices.

[image: Choosing Attribute Selection Algorithm]

Once you have made your choices for the feature selection algorithm,
click `Apply` to the right of the filter bar so that the filter is
actually applied to the data. The data should now have the reduced
feature set.  So all you need to do is save it by clicking on the
`Save` button at the top right.

[image: Apply Filter and Save]

This should save the reduced data set.